# Firebase, React - onChildAdded for query reference

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

Within my app, I want to listen for children being added, therfore I use the `onChildAdded` listener. When the listener is initally invoked, I don't want to get all the data at the location, only the latest entry, and I want to listen to new children added at the location.

I wrote the following code to try acheieve this:

```
  // Only get the last entry at the location
  let queryRef = query(child(dbRef, `messages/${cd.key}`), limitToLast(1))

  // This should initially only get the last entry, and then listen to future changes, i.e new children
  onChildAdded(queryRef).then((snap) => {
    console.log(snap.val());
  })
```

However, when running the code, I get the following error stating:

> (0 , firebase_database__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.onChildAdded)(...).then is not a function

After searching for other solutions, I found the a solution which I believe would fix this issue, however the code is outdated. Here is that code:

```
var queryRef = ref.orderBy('created').startAt(Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

queryRef.on('child_added', function(snap) {
  console.log(snap.val());
});
```

How could I ammend my solution so that I only initially get the latest entry at the location, and then all the new children added. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code you shared in your question uses the namespaced API of Firebase:

```
var queryRef = ref.orderBy('created').startAt(Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

queryRef.on('child_added', function(snap) {
  console.log(snap.val());
});
```

The equivalent in the modular API would be:

```
var queryRef = query(ref, orderByChild('created'), startAt(Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP));

onChildAdded(queryRef, function(snap) {
  console.log(snap.val());
});
```

If you watch closely, you'll see that it's mostly a matter of moving things around. To learn more about these two APIs and how they map on each other, see the documentation on [Upgrade from the namespaced API to the modular API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).

---

Note that I don't think the approach in this snippet will work, as `startAt(Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP)` won't work. Honestly, the simplest way to get just new children would be something like:

```
var queryRef = query(ref, orderByChild('created'), limitToLast(1));

onChildAdded(queryRef, function(snap) {
  console.log(snap.val());
});
```

Here you'll get the latest child when you first run `onChildAdded` (there's no way to avoid this) and then only new children after that.

Comment: Hello, after implementing the code from your answer, I got the following error: `Reference_impl.ts:2256 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: constraint._apply is not a function`. I think the error comes from the line where the query is written.

Comment: Hmm... did you check the [reference docs for `query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md#query) already? I thought it'd take a number of conditions, but maybe it must be an array.

Comment: I changed `orderBy`, to `orderByChild`and everything seems to work ok. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Oops... that's a good catch. I should've caught that mistake in the original code. Wherever you got that from, it's not a great example - as it definitely won't work, and likely won't even compile on the original SDK version it targeted. --- I updated the code in my answer to match.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the explanation.